# Accessing webcam mic from command line version of FFMPEG for android

Tags: android, command-line, ffmpeg, webcam, audio-streaming

I am currently testing audio and video streaming from a **webcam** using a **command line version of FFMPEG on an android box**. I am having a problem accessing the webcam mic
Using Ubuntu as a reference, the correct command to determine the recording devices available is    **arecord -L** . Unfortunately **arecord -L**  does not work on the Android box  
 The current command option **alsa** for accessing the webcam mic is    **ffmpeg -f alsa -alsa_device_name..**  and the previous option of **oss** does not work either, ie  **ffmpeg -f -oss..** does not work either.
 The listed audio devices shown in  **/dev/snd**  shows the mic portion of the webcam as  **pcmC3D0c**  and  **controlC3**. The reason I know this is because if I unplug the webcam these values vanish from the directory listing.
 Has anyone tried successfully to access the mic portion of a webcam using ffmpeg on an android box?
 How do you formulate the correct format of the command to access the **webcam** mic. 
Please note that I am able to access the audio and video on my Ubuntu PC using ffmpeg hence i know that both devices work

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out what I was doing wrong. The issue was with my build of FFMpeg
 To use either the camera or mic portion(s) of a webcam, one needs to call the device(s) using the appropriate format(s) in FFMPEG. The camera portion is controlled by **video4linux2**, while the mic portion of the webcam is controlled by **alsa**.
 I should have checked and made sure that my build of FFMPEG had both formats - **alsa** and **video4linux** available in my FFMPEG build.
 The command to use is  **./ffmpeg -formats**  The output would show somewhere in the output listing as  **DE alsa**  for sound, which means **alsa** is available for Decoding and Encoding. Likewise for the video portion,  **D video4linux**  - meaning that **video4linux** was available to decoode the video coming from the camera portion of the webcam.
. Because **alsa** was not available, the command **./ffmpeg -f alsa...**   always gave a syntax error
 I guess the lesson is check your ffmpeg build for all the features you need to make sure they are there before you attempt to use it.
 "Thank you" to all who looked at the question!